# Pop up or notification in webOS

Tags: webos

From a service, is there any way to create a pop up, application which is registered to my service may/may not be available, so i need to show a pop up/toast/notification message to user, is that possible in webOS

Comment: this may not be related to the question, but i reli wanted to know if the market of webOS still exists. ?

Comment: @DharaShah : it exists that's the reason question was asked.... but not on the larger level, too me its limited for developers space only :)

Answer (score 0):

While I've never written a service, I don't see why this wouldn't be possible. Can a service launch an application? If so, set your application's no window mode to true. Launch the app, with some parameter indicating why it was launched. In the relaunch handler, check if that parameter is there, and if so, create a popup.